# How do I clone a WCF binding?

Tags: .net, wcf

Given that the `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding` class in WCF does not have a `Clone` method, what is an efficient way of making a complete, deep copy of a `Binding`, without writing out all the possible properties by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind treating everything as a `CustomBinding`, you could do this:

```
WSHttpBinding original = new WSHttpBinding();
CustomBinding copy = new CustomBinding(original);
```

This works because all of the system-provided bindings are equivalent to a `CustomBinding` with the binding elements pre-configured. Cloning the binding this way means that you don't have to know the type of the binding in advance, and you certainly don't have to spend a day typing out every possible property of the `Binding` types you need.